# 10th degree polynomial regression function the easy way?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am quite new to R and I am asked to generate the 10th degree polynomial regression function. During the course I learned it that way for example a 3 degree polynomial regression:

```
reg_poly3 = lm_robust(testscr ~ avginc + I(avginc^2) + I(avginc^3), data=school)
```

I find it very annoying to do this for the 10th degree so is there an easy way for example with a for loop or so?

Comment: Check `poly()`.

Comment: Could you explain the raw specification?

Comment: irislm <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width + I(Petal.Width^2),data=iris);
summary(irislm);

irislm2 <- lm(Petal.Length ~ poly(Petal.Width,
                                  degree = 2,
                                  raw = TRUE),data=iris);
summary(irislm2)

Comment: A 10th degree polynomial is massively overfitting and results in a nonsensical model.

Comment: @Roland Yes but it looks cool.

Comment: @Roland Agreed, however since OP was asked to do it, it seems plausible it's a learning exercise.

Comment: @robert ecaxtly.